# Polygonizing distinct values using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygonize, values

I am using QGIS 3.0.3 and I am trying to create simulated data through two sets random points distributed along two gradients of values (photo below).  Using the raster calculator I created two rasters with multiple bands that represent those values.  In reading about how to create random points, I found that I needed to have polygons to use the random point generator.  After a bit of futzing with some human error, I finally was able to polygonize the raster but there weren't any values associated with the polygons when the file was created (photo also below).

[image]

[image]

How can I preserve the distinct values of the raster in the polygon (i.e., the area that has a value of 1 in the raster having a value of 1 in the polygon file)?

Comment: The raster values should be preserved as attributes. What field name did you enter in the box for "Name of the field to create"?

Comment: You may want to choose a categorized style based on that field. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of your vector attribute table of the layer you are using to convert to raster? Can be helpful to suggest the specific solution.

Comment: I am realizing, that most of my issues with this is just that my transition to QGIS from Arc has not been seamless.  I appreciate the suggestions you have all given and I am starting to feel that, even though I spent a day reading through what I thought was important to my task, I was not looking in the correct directions.  I appreciate your patience with this obviously basic question.  After looking in the Attribute table I found that the values for those vectors were retained.  Thank you csk and Hasnein Tareque for your direction on this issue.